# How do I prevent an image from the last view showing up in the current one?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to cycle through a series of images in Fancybox popup window here: http://ee.rouviere.com/web/portfolio

To see what is happening, click on any one of the thumbnail images. Inside the popup window click on a thumbnail to the left and it shows a larger view of that same image to the right. This all works fine. However, when you close out that window and open another one, the last large image still shows in the new window until you click on another thumbnail.

I need to find a way to "clear the cache" from the last window when a new window loads.

Here is the html for this section:

```
<div class="portfolio_popup_thumb">
        <a class="image-preview" href="#portfolio-frame-544"><img src="http://ee.rouviere.com/images/uploads/webPortFEC_thumb.jpg" alt="photo" /></a>

        <p>Family Eye Care of Apex</p>
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="portfolio-frame-544">
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="preview">
            <img class="photo_large" src="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-of-Apex-home-large.jpg" alt="Family Eye Care of Apex" />
        </div>

        <div class="viewer">
            <div class="thumbs">
                <div class="thumb1">
                    <a href="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-of-Apex-home-large.jpg" title="For Family Eye Care of Apex in Apex, North Carolina, we built a content management site that can be updated as new services are added and the company has expanded. The doctors in this practice wanted patients to have an easy on-line way to get information about specific eye conditions such as cataracts and low vision. The site also includes the capability to download patient forms, order contacts and glasses on-line, make on-line payments and schedule appointments. The site has google maps to the office location, google search within the site and search engine optimization. "><img src="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-of-Apex-home-portthumb.jpg" alt="Family Eye Care of Apex" class="web-port" /></a>
                </div>
                                                    <div class="thumb2">
                    <a href="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-of-Apex-exams-large.jpg" title="Family Eye Care of Apex also wanted patients to know what to expect before they have an eye exam. We created this slide show to walk them through the procedure. "><img src="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-of-Apex_portthumb.jpg" alt="Family Eye Care of Apex" class="web-port" /></a>
                </div>
                                                                                        <div class="thumb3">

                    <a href="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-items-montage.jpg" title="We also have designed a large number of other items for Family Eye Care of Apex, including business and appointment scheduling cards, brochures, magazine and web banner ads, coupons and flyers. "><img src="http://ee.rouviere.com/_photos/Family-Eye-Care-brochure-portthumb.jpg" alt="Family Eye Care of Apex" class="web-port" /></a>
                </div>
                                                    <div class="thumb4">
                                                        <p>Visit the website:</p>
                    <p class="site-url"><a href="http://www.familyeyecareofapex.com">http://www.familyeyecareofapex.com</a></p>

                </div>

            </div><!-- end thumbs -->
            <div class="info-box">

                <p class="caption1">For Family Eye Care of Apex in Apex, North Carolina, we built a content management site that can be updated as new services are added and the company has expanded. The doctors in this practice wanted patients to have an easy on-line way to get information about specific eye conditions such as cataracts and low vision. The site also includes the capability to download patient forms, order contacts and glasses on-line, make on-line payments and schedule appointments. The site has google maps to the office location, google search within the site and search engine optimization. </p>
            </div>
            </div><!-- end frame -->
         </div><!-- end portfolio frame -->
    </div><!-- end viewer --> 
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery that drives the image swap out:

```
 $("a:has(img.web-port)").click(function() {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $(".photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
    $(".caption1").text(caption);
    return false;
  });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how fancy box works, here's my guess:

When you click an image inside the fancy box, you're custom function changes the src of the main image to the src of the click image. However, when a user clicks the 'close' button, I don't see any code to clear the src of the large image. Try clearing those values when someone hits the close button. For example:

```
$("#fancybox-close").click(function(){
    $(".photo_large").attr({ src: ''});
    $(".caption1").text('');
});
```

This will either fix your problem or cause the image to be broken, depending on how Fancybox works.

If it's the later, post a link to the un-minified version of fancybox and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Nick. That is a step in the right direction. Please take a look at the page and give it a try. What it does now is that it clears the values so the second screen loads with only the thumbnails showing. Now all we need to do is figure out how to get the first large image to load. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. It looks like you got it working though! Nice job. Glad I could help a bit.